# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my index page I am trying to create a modal that contains a form so that users can create users on the index page. I am using devise to create these users.

However, when I try to create the form for this in the modal, I get this error.

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_account, only: [:index, :new, :create]

  def index
    if params[:email].present?
      @users = User.where(email: params[:email]).first
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
    respond_with @users
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'User was sucessfully created' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password)
    end

    def find_account
      @account ||= Account.find(params[:account_id])
    end
end
```

The user is a nested route because it belongs to an account:

```
new_account_user GET /accounts/:account_id/users/new(.:format)   users#new
```

Does anybody know why I am getting this error? Since I am creating the `@user` variable in my controller and finding the `account_id` in the before_action I am not sure what the problem is.

#### Update:

If I implement this feature in another form that is working it gives the same error. Possibly something having to do with this not being on the correct action page?

Answer (score 0):

You defined `@user` but using `@material` in form and of course `@material` is `nil` -> throw the errors.

If the user belongs to account, so the form should be:

```
<%= form_for [@account, @user], html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

If the user is independent, so the form should be:

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```